gdExtension C++ failed to load gdexample.gdextension in Godot 4.1
I have followed the guidelines carefully on how to use gdExtension with c++ from the official site
GDExtension with C++
Everything else seems okay but when I launched the Godot 4.1 editor, this error appears:
Error loading extension: res://bin/gdexample.gdextension

This is what my gdexample.gdextension looks like
[configuration]

entry_symbol = "example_library_init"
compatibility_minimum = "4.1"

[libraries]

macos.debug = "res://bin/libgdexample.macos.template_debug.framework"
macos.release = "res://bin/libgdexample.macos.template_release.framework"
windows.debug.x86_32 = "res://bin/libgdexample.windows.template_debug.x86_32.dll"
windows.release.x86_32 = "res://bin/libgdexample.windows.template_release.x86_32.dll"
windows.debug.x86_64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.windows.template_debug.x86_64.dll"
windows.release.x86_64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.windows.template_release.x86_64.dll"
linux.debug.x86_64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.linux.template_debug.x86_64.so"
linux.release.x86_64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.linux.template_release.x86_64.so"
linux.debug.arm64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.linux.template_debug.arm64.so"
linux.release.arm64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.linux.template_release.arm64.so"
linux.debug.rv64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.linux.template_debug.rv64.so"
linux.release.rv64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.linux.template_release.rv64.so"
android.debug.x86_64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.android.template_debug.x86_64.so"
android.release.x86_64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.android.template_release.x86_64.so"
android.debug.arm64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.android.template_debug.arm64.so"
android.release.arm64 = "res://bin/libgdexample.android.template_release.arm64.so"

I'm new to Godot and I don't have interest learning gdscript, how can I get rid of this error and be able to proceed with my learning

As mentioned on the official docs you linked, GDExtension is currently experimental & has some finicky compatibility issues. Can you edit to include the version of Godot you're using?

The version has just been added... Both editor and source code uses exactly Godot 4.1
